# RavenDB select documents by index field

Tags: c#, nosql, ravendb

I'm new to RaveDB (Actually I've started learn it only yesterday). And try to implement some functionality.

Lets we have next class hierarchy:

```
public abstract class Transaction
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryTransaction : Transaction
{
    public string AccountId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Category { get; set; }

    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}

public class ExchangeTransaction : Transaction
{
    public string DebitAccountId { get; set; }

    public string CreditAccountId { get; set; }

    public decimal DebitAmount { get; set; }

    public decimal CreditAmount { get; set; }
}
```

Everything storing excelent int db. I event add `Conventions = FindTypeTagName ...` for store documents as 'transactions/*' document id.

But I want to create index for select all transactions for specific Account (by field AccountId). I've create index:

```
public class AccountTransactionResult
{
    public string AccId { get; set; }
}

public class Account_Transactions : AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<AccountTransactionResult>
{
    public Account_Transactions()
    {
        this.AddMap<CategoryTransaction>( transactions => from transaction in transactions
                                                            select new
                                                                    {
                                                                    AccId = transaction.AccountId
                                                                    } );
        this.AddMap<ExchangeTransaction>( transactions => from transaction in transactions
                                                            select new
                                                                    {
                                                                    AccId = transaction.DebitAccountId
                                                                    } );
        this.AddMap<ExchangeTransaction>( transactions => from transaction in transactions
                                                            select new
                                                                    {
                                                                    AccId = transaction.CreditAccountId
                                                                    } );
    }
}
```

This index works well I can't get all type of transactions from DB (Exchange and Category) as single `IEnumerable<Transaction>`. That is great.

But I want to use the index to return transactions only for particular account. Because `ExchangeTransaction` can belong to two `Accounts`. I want to see `ExchangeTransaction` for both `Accounts`. I can make query in Raven Studio by AccId (index field) and it works greate! But I can't create the same request in the code :(.

Can someone help me? How can I use index field AccId in C# LINQ query?

This code

```
var query = session.Query<Transaction, Account_Transactions>()
```

return all type of transaction, but I don't how to filter the transactions by index field in the DB.

Thanks in advance. And please sorry me my English, it is not my native language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My fault, in [documentation](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/querying/polymorphism) everythings is clear. I missed some useful paragraph.

> The easiest way to do this is by writing a multi-map index like this
>   one:
>
> ```
> public class AnimalsIndex : AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask
> {
>     public AnimalsIndex()
>     {
>         AddMap<Cat>(cats => from c in cats
>                             select new { c.Name });
>
>         AddMap<Dog>(dogs => from d in dogs
>                             select new { d.Name });
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> And query it like this:

```
var results = session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<object>("AnimalsIndex")
    .WhereEquals("Name", "Mitzy");
```

>

In my case I should use next construction:

```
var transactions = session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<Transaction>( "Account/Transactions" )
                    .WhereEquals( "AccId", account2.Id )
```

And everything is working now.